# Should I use dictionary to store location of non-zero pixels?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a binary image. I want to store location `(x,y)` of all non-zero pixels to use it for searching in future.

```
import numpy as np
I = np.random.randint(2, size=(128,128))
pos_nonzero = np.where(I==1)
```

In future, I will randomly pick up a position of the non-zero pixel to use. Which kind of method (dictionary or list ) should I use in here? Thanks

Comment: I think a list makes more sense than a dictionary, because then you can generate a random index and take that pixel. If you have a dictionary what will you use as the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.argwhere` to get a 2D array of positions from which you can sample later using `np.random.choice`:

```
indices = np.argwhere(image)
sample_indices = np.random.choice(len(indices), size=5, replace=False)
pixels = image[tuple(indices[sample_indices].T)]
```